Image in google drive not viewing in google sheet
The image saved in google drive is not viewing in the google sheet, instead it appears as folder name along with image name.
The image is saved through the APPSHEET and I need that image to be view in google sheet. The image is stored in my google drive but it is not viewing.

Will you be able to share your sample sheet where it shows how you are trying to display the image on your sheet?

This question is similar to: How display images from Google Drive on Gsheet cell?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have created an APPSHEET for 5 to 8 users with the use of GOOGLE SHEET. Whenever I have uploaded any image in APSHEET will not appears in the GOOGLE SHEET, Instead it appears as an folder name and image name. The image actually stored in my drive. I want that image to be view/visible in google sheet automatically. So please help me to make that image view which been upload through APPSHEET.

Not much details here but, You can try to get the Direct Link to the image.
You will need to convert the image reference to a direct link that Google Sheets can understand.

Go to Google Drive and locate the image.
Right-click on the image and select Get Link.
Ensure that the link sharing is set to Anyone with the link can view.
Copy the link provided.


Thanks for the response, but it seems like manual work, It would be helpful if any option that intended to make the image visible instead image name when I'm uploading through appsheet .
